# how to add a button next to the wordpress view button?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, theme-development

I'm trying to add an example button like in the photo for Wordpress plugin

[image: example image]

I should create a button that sends me to a page created by me in the wordpress dashboard.

It should apply to a post type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. the function is

`apply_filters( 'page_row_actions', string[] $actions, WP_Post $post )`

[Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_row_actions/)

For the custom post type need to not be `hierarchical` and it's work